# SQL Wildcards for space or nothing

Tags: sql, wildcard

I am using wildcards in a join statement to find when a specific phrase is contained in a text field. Originally, I tried something like:

```
[Text Field] LIKE '%[^0-9A-Z]' + [Phrase] + '[^0-9A-Z]%'
```

However, this only gives me results that contain the phrase inside of the text field surrounded by spaces or special characters. Instead I need it to be when the phrase is surrounded by a leading or trailing space, or if the phrase is at the beginning or end of text field. Does anyone have any idea on how to accomplish this? I have searched around to no avail.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using,.

Comment: Why do you have what looks like *regex character classes* in your `LIKE` expression? `LIKE` is not regex, so a simple "text field *contains* phrase" would be `[Text Field] LIKE '%' + [Phrase] + '%'`, assuming you're on a SQL dialect where `+` is used for string concatenation.

Comment: Because if I surround the phrase by only '%' then it will flag anytime phrase is conatined in a text field. I only want it to flag when the phrase is surrounded by spaces or nothing. For example, if the text field was "I cannot figure this out", I don't want "not figure" to flag

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you are using SQL Server.  Just add spaces to the beginning and end of the column:

```
' ' + [Text Field] + ' ' LIKE '%[^0-9A-Z]' + [Phrase] + '[^0-9A-Z]%'
```

Comment: Hi Gordon thank you for your answer. Will this affect indexing? Also this means that it will still pick up special characters.

Comment: @Kenny . . . Not at all because your original query can't use an index either (at least in most databases).